# Can Fiddler monitor traffic other than HTTP

Tags: fiddler

I have developed a Client/Server type application.  XML data is passed between the client and server.  I want to simulate how it would run on a very slow network (i.e. radio @ 9.6kps).  I understand Fiddler can be used in **simulate modem speeds** mode.  But no matter what I do I cannot configure Fiddler to accept traffic from the client and redirect it to the server.  And I have also tried a "reverse proxy" too.

Does Fiddler work with protocols other than HTTP?

Comment: if you can leverage linux, you can use [`trickle` or `wondershaper`](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-bandwidth-shapers-wondershaper-or-trickle-to-limit-internet-connection-speed.html)

Comment: Unfortunately both server and client are windows based.

Comment: What protocol is the client actually using? Fiddler can intercept traffic from any HTTP/HTTPS application that support a proxy, which, in practice, is basically all of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what kind of traffic fiddler can capture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740761/what-kind-of-traffic-fiddler-can-capture)

Comment: yes, agree with Paul Seatte.   Fiddler2 can only intercept HTTP, HTTPS and FTP traffic.   Your client-server communications might be using SSH or RPC which will not be captured.