# what kind of traffic fiddler can capture?

Tags: fiddler

When I open fiddler, http traffic from browser can be captured.

I wrote a program using .net HttpWebRequest, the traffic can also be captured.

Also using python urllib2, fiddler captures the http traffic.

Does fiddler capture all http traffic from my machine when I open fiddler without changing any default setting of fiddler? There's no custom filter of fiddler.

Fiddler is supposed to be proxy server. what does it do when it's opened?

Answer (score 11):

Fiddler is a proxy server. It captures HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP traffic that is sent to it, and then forwards that traffic to the server.

By default, when Fiddler starts, it sets itself as the "system" proxy. Most, but not all applications will automatically send their traffic to  Fiddler for that reason. Virtually all other applications can be reconfigured to proxy their traffic through Fiddler.

Comment: "system" proxy is interesting. It seems .net HttpWebRequest will use the system proxy by default http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx.

Comment: @EricLaw, Why do you say "Virtually all other applications can be reconfigured to proxy their traffic through Fiddler"? For example, how would you configure games to route their traffic through Fiddler since there are no options to do so?

Comment: Because virtually all apps can be reconfigured. Of course, non-browser games typically do not use HTTP.

Comment: Doesn't it capture WebSocket traffic as well?